# Searching for IS_DATE equivalent in Hive using Pyspark

Tags: sql, date, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, hive

I have multiple date formats coming in source data and I am trying to convert all of them to a similar format.

I tried below code but its not working.

`df.createOrReplaceTempView("df")
sqlContext.sql("select decode(V2_EVENT_DATE, is_date(V2_EVENT_DATE,'mm/dd/yy'),to_date(V2_EVENT_DATE,'mm/dd/yy'), is_date(V2_EVENT_DATE,'month dd,yyyy'),to_date(V2_EVENT_DATE,'month dd,yyyy'), is_date(V2_EVENT_DATE,'dd month,yyyy'),to_date(V2_EVENT_DATE,'dd month,yyyy'), is_date(V2_EVENT_DATE,'mm/dd/yyyy'),to_date(V2_EVENT_DATE,'mm/dd/yyyy'), is_date(V2_EVENT_DATE,'dd/mm/yyyy'),to_date(V2_EVENT_DATE,'dd/mm/yyyy'), is_date(V2_EVENT_DATE,'dd month yyyy'),to_date(V2_EVENT_DATE,'dd month yyyy'), is_date(V2_EVENT_DATE,'yyyy'),to_date(V2_EVENT_DATE||'/12/31','yyyy/mm/dd'), is_date(V2_EVENT_DATE,'dd month yyyy'),to_date(V2_EVENT_DATE,'dd month yyyy'), is_date(V2_EVENT_DATE,'month dd yyyy'),to_date(V2_EVENT_DATE,'month dd yyyy'), is_date(V2_EVENT_DATE,'dd-Mon-yy'),to_date(V2_EVENT_DATE,'dd-Mon-yy'), is_date(V2_EVENT_DATE,'ddmmyy'),to_date(V2_EVENT_DATE,'ddmmyy'), is_date(V2_EVENT_DATE,'mmddyy'),to_date(V2_EVENT_DATE,'mmddyy'), null) EVENT_DATE_CLEANED from df")`

Error:

`AnalysisException: u"Undefined function: 'is_date'. This function is neither a registered temporary function nor a permanent function registered in the database 'default'.; line 1 pos 29"`

Basically I am searching for a function which is equivalent to SQL IS_DATE in Hive or in Pyspark. I am unable to develop this in dataframe as I am again struck in this date check or IS_DATE part, that's why tried Hive temp view. I am new to Pyspark. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
case when unix_timestamp(date_col,'MM/dd/yy') is not null then to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(date_col,'MM/dd/yy')))
     when unix_timestamp(date_col,'MMM dd,yyyy') is not null then to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(date_col,'MMM dd,yyyy')))
     when ... and so on
 end as event_date_cleaned
```

Date formats should be fixed. See date/time pattern reference here: [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/simpleDateFormat.html)

And you can easily test format string in hive like this:

```
select to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('Aug 14,2019','MMM dd,yyyy')));
```

Returns:

```
2019-08-14
Time taken: 0.056 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```